# Segmentation Fault Before function is even called

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

When I try executing this code, the code crashes before the `cout` statement in `print_array` even executes. I have no clue why !
However, if I comment out the call to `mergesort` in the main function, the `print_array` executes fine.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void print_array( int A[], int n)
{
    int i;
    cout<<"\n Array elts:\t";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) cout<<A[i]<<" ";
}
void mergesort(int A[], int beg, int end)
{
    if(beg>end) return;
    mergesort(A,beg,(beg+end)/2);
    mergesort(A, ((beg+end)/2)+1, end);
    int B[end-beg+1],i,j,k;
    i=beg; j=(beg+end)/2;
    k=0;
    while(i<(beg+end)/2 && j<end)
    {
        if(A[i] < A[j]) B[k++]=A[i++];
        else B[k++]=A[j++];
    }
    while(i<(beg+end)/2) B[k++]=A[i++];
    while(j<end) B[k++]=A[j++];
    for(i=beg; i<end; i++) A[i]=B[i];       

}   
int main()
{
    int n=10;
    int A[]={1,23,34,4,56,60,71,8,99,0};
    print_array(A,n);
    mergesort(A,0,n);
    print_array(A,n);
}
```

Update:
Using `endl` will flush the output and the `print_array` values will get displayed on the screen. Apart from this, the reason I got a seg fault was because I had not included the equality check in `mergesort`. Here is the updated code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void print_array( int A[], int n)
{
    int i;
    cout<<"\n Array elts:\t";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) cout<<A[i]<<" ";
}
void mergesort(int A[], int beg, int end)
{
    if(beg>=end) return;
    mergesort(A,beg,(beg+end)/2);
    mergesort(A, ((beg+end)/2)+1, end);
    int B[end-beg+1],i,j,k;
    i=beg; j=(beg+end)/2;
    k=0;
    while(i<(beg+end)/2 && j<end)
    {
        if(A[i] < A[j]) B[k++]=A[i++];
        else B[k++]=A[j++];
    }
    while(i<(beg+end)/2) B[k++]=A[i++];
    while(j<end) B[k++]=A[j++];
    for(i=beg; i<end; i++) A[i]=B[i];       

}   
int main()
{
    int n=10;
    int A[]={1,23,34,4,56,60,71,8,99,0};
    print_array(A,n);
    mergesort(A,0,n);
    print_array(A,n);
}
```

The code is by no means doing what it should but it isn't giving seg faults anymore.
Thanks guys !

Comment: On what line does your debugger say the seg fault occurs?

Comment: Your're not flushing the output. Add an `endl`.

Comment: I added `int` to `main`. As posted your code shouldn't have compiled as C++. C++ does not have the *implicit int* that original C had. Which leads to the question: is this the real code?

Comment: My code does compile....



Also, the gdb output says seg fault in mergesort(int*, int, int) ()

Comment: I tried on C++98 and C++11 ( using -std=c++11 with g++).

Comment: Which line in `mergesort`?  Which recursive iteration?  What were the variables values before it crashes?

Comment: The C++ language doesn't like Variable Length Arrays: `int B[beg-int+1]`.  I recommend you use *dynamic memory allocation* instead.  VLA is a language extension by G++.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Tried using malloc and new but I still get the same seg fault in the same place !

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last line in `mergesort`: You're accessing elements in `B` from `beg` to `end`, but `B` is zero indexed.  That's one problem; there may be more.

Comment: The issue is that the program crashes even before the `mergesort` function is called. It doesn't even print the elements as done in `print_array`

Comment: @LockStock As mentioned in one of the comments to your question, your output isn't being flushed, so you're not seeing it.  You need to add a `cout << endl` to the end of your `print_array` function.

Comment: Ah yes, that was it !

Answer (score 0):

My first though is that this is a Stack Corruption which is leading to a "Stack Overflow" when you call other methods. Try getting additional information in GDB, try compiling increasing the debugging level and turning off the optimizations of gcc (i.e., -g3 -O0).

Moreover, you can use the "valgrind" software to find the corruption and post the results here. (Sorry for requesting this here, but I cannot make comments).